# WCF: Getting exception when making concurrent requests

Tags: wcf

I am seeing several problems in my application. Here is sample code to reproduce the problem.

Service:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]        
        string GetData(int value, int minDelaySeconds, int maxDelaySeconds);     
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]    
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Simulates an operation. Generates a random string, and sleeps for sometime to simulate a long running operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">length of string</param>
        /// <param name="min">minimum time delay. units: seconds</param>
        /// <param name="max">maximum time delay. units: seconds</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GetData(int value, int min, int max)
        {            
            var r = new Random();
            var bytes = new byte[value];
            r.NextBytes(bytes);
            var s = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min));
            return s;
        }
    }
```

service config (using a custom binding):

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="myHttpBinding">
          <reliableSession />
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

client (makes parallel calls to service):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var tw = Console.Out)
            {
                try
                {
                    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
                    int numberOfthreads, minDelay, maxDelay, minPayLoad, maxPayLoad, numberOfRequests;
                    ParseCmdArgs(args, out numberOfthreads, out minDelay, out maxDelay, out minPayLoad, out maxPayLoad, out numberOfRequests);
                    var interceptor = new Interceptor();                    
                    var r = new Random();
                    using (var svc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
                    {
                        svc.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(interceptor);
                        var tasks = new Task[numberOfthreads];
                        int threadId = 0;
                        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < numberOfthreads; ctr++)
                        {
                            tasks[ctr] = Task.Run(async () =>
                            {
                                int id = Interlocked.Increment(ref threadId);
                                var count = 0;
                                while (count < numberOfRequests)
                                {                                    
                                    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = id.ToString();                                
                                    await svc.GetDataAsync(r.Next(minPayLoad, maxPayLoad), minDelay, maxDelay);
                                    // you will be on a different thread now, than the thread which made the call
                                    Debug.Assert(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)); // note
                                    count++;
                                }
                                tw.WriteLine("Thread {0} is exiting...", id);
                            });
                        }
                        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LogException(e, tw);
                }
            }         
        }
```

client config:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
...
<customBinding>              
                <binding name="myHttpBinding">
                    <reliableSession />
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
```

Questions:

1. I am only seeing serial request processing. Why?
2. Often there is a big time delay (how big? more than 60s at times) between when message leaves server, and it reaches client. What is happening in-between? Both service and client are on same machine. I have shown client times below, and omitted service trace for sake of brevity.
3. An exception happens on the client, when threads are about to exit. See below. Why, and how to fix this?
4. Can someone show me how to revise the client method so that it does not create multiple threads to make the concurrent requests? The solution should be subject to the constraint that it does not use any lock statement.

// explanation of cmd line parameters: 5 requests in parallel, time delay between 5-30s, message size between 100kb-1MB, each "thread" makes 5 calls before exiting

```
c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication8\Test
Client1\bin\Debug>run2 5 5 30 100000 1000000 5  
[2] 1 Sending request...Received Response 502,492.00 bytes in 18.8 sec  
[3] 2 Sending request...Received Response 313,662.00 bytes in 29.0 sec  
[4] 3 Sending request...Received Response 1,236,254.00 bytes in 27.5 sec  
[1] 4 Sending request...Received Response 1,250,170.00 bytes in 36.3 sec  
[5] 5 Sending request...Received Response 151,803.00 bytes in 54.8 sec  
[2] 6 Sending request...Received Response 625,859.00 bytes in 26.8 sec  
[4] 7 Sending request...Received Response 395,976.00 bytes in 47.6 sec  
[3] 8 Sending request...Received Response 945,664.00 bytes in 45.1 sec  
[1] 9 Sending request...Received Response 1,287,904.00 bytes in 73.5 sec  
[2] 10 Sending request...Received Response 1,312,428.00 bytes in 52.9 sec  
[5] 11 Sending request...Received Response 1,045,727.00 bytes in 103.3 sec  
[3] 12 Sending request...Received Response 190,310.00 bytes in 107.5 sec  
[4] 13 Sending request...  
[2] 14 Sending request...  
[1] 15 Sending request...  
[5] 16 Sending request...Received Response 1,323,274.00 bytes in 36.4 sec  
[3] 17 Sending request...Received Response 1,090,367.00 bytes in 13.4 sec  
[5] 18 Sending request...Received Response 458,598.00 bytes in 28.8 sec  
[3] 19 Sending request...Received Response 1,185,986.00 bytes in 28.3 sec  
[5] 20 Sending request...Received Response 731,178.00 bytes in 27.0 sec  
Thread 3 is exiting...  
Thread 5 is exiting...  



One or more errors occurred.  
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeou
t)  
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks)  
   at TestClient1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\me\Documents\Vis  
ual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication8\TestClient1\Program.cs:line 48  
The message could not be transferred within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. Th  
ere was no space available in the reliable channel's transfer window. The time a  
llotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)  
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncR  
esult result)  
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[  
] outs, IAsyncResult result)  
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayC  
lass5`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)  
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar,  
Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchron  
ization)  
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot  
ification(Task task)  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
   at TestClient1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass8.<<Main>b__0>d__a.MoveNext() in c:\U  
sers\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication8\TestClie  
nt1\Program.cs:line 40
```

Answer (score 0):

1. see (2).
2. My initial thought was concurrency Mode not being set to multiple.  But, I see that this is set after all.  You may be getting throttled.  Sessions are defaulted to 10 I believe.  So, if you're not setting a throttle for session, this could be what's causing it. Try bumping up your maxConncurentSessions in the ServiceThrottlingBehavior to a higher number (20 for example).
3. The solution to 1 & 2 will likely solve this problem since you appear to be exceeding your idle timeout setting.  If you can open things up a bit more then I think this will go away.

Something you may want to change is the using construct .... using (var svc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())  on the client.  See this document for details.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx.  You should use a try/finally construct instead when using WCF proxies.